# Appending Excel Sheets after Web Scraping

Tags: python, excel, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have successfully scraped data from the website https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/Reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx. I made an excel file with the results for one commodity. After scraping the data for the second commodity, I am unable to add another sheet to the same excel file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. This is my code: -

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time, re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/Reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx")

html_source = driver.page_source
results=[]

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_1"]""").click()
element_variation = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option1")
drp_variation = Select(element_variation)
drp_variation.select_by_visible_text("Daily Variation")

driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate").send_keys("01/05/2020")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_ToDate").send_keys("27/05/2020")

element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_MainContent_Lst_Commodity")
drp_commodity = Select(element_commodity)
drp_commodity.select_by_visible_text("Rice")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btn_getdata1"]""").click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2] #second table is the one that we want
print(len(table))
print(table)

results.append(table)
driver.back()
time.sleep(1)
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx') as writer:
 table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "rice", index=False) # Rice results on sheet named rice
 writer.save() 

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btn_back"]""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_1"]""").click()
element_variation = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option1")
drp_variation = Select(element_variation)
drp_variation.select_by_visible_text("Daily Variation")

driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate").send_keys("01/05/2020")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_Txt_ToDate").send_keys("27/05/2020")

element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_MainContent_Lst_Commodity")
drp_commodity = Select(element_commodity)
drp_commodity.select_by_visible_text("Wheat")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btn_getdata1"]""").click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2] #second table is the one that we want
print(len(table))
print(table)

results.append(table)
driver.back()
time.sleep(1)

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx') as writer:
 table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "wheat", index=False) # Wheat results on sheet named wheat
 writer.save()
```

Comment: for some type of files you may have to read all data to memory, add new data, and save all data again to file. For some other files you have to use "append" mode - and maybe `ExcelWriter` has something like this. Did you check documetation for `ExcelWriter` and `to_excel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some type of files you may have to read all data to memory, add new data, and save all data again to file. For some other files you have to use "append" mode.

See documentation for [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) it has option `mode="a"` to append to existing file

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx') as writer:
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="rice", index=False)
    #writer.save() 

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="wheat", index=False)
    #writer.save()
```

Or you can do it in one `with` without append

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx') as writer:
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="rice", index=False)
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="wheat", index=False)
    #writer.save()
```

---

**BTW:** I find out `append` mode doesn't work with engine `xlsxwriter` and I had to use engine `openpyxl` (it also means to install module `openpyxl` with `pip`)

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'python.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
```

I found available engines in question [Engines available for to_excel function in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571026/engines-available-for-to-excel-function-in-pandas)

---

Full working code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time

# --- functions ---

def get_data(start_date, end_date, product):

    # select `Variation Report`
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_1').click()

    # select `Daily Variant`
    element_variation = driver.find_element_by_id ('ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option1')
    drop_variation = Select(element_variation)
    drop_variation.select_by_visible_text('Daily Variation')

    # select `product` before `date` because `end_date` opens calendar which blocks `product` list
    element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ('ctl00_MainContent_Lst_Commodity')
    drop_commodity = Select(element_commodity)
    drop_commodity.select_by_visible_text(product)

    # select `start_date` and `end_date`    
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate').send_keys(start_date)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_Txt_ToDate').send_keys(end_date)

    # click button `Get Data`
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_btn_getdata1').click()

    time.sleep(3)  # sometimes it need to wait for loading page

    #second table is the one that we want    
    table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2]

    print(len(table))
    print(table)

    # go back
    driver.find_element_by_id('btn_back').click()

    time.sleep(3)  # sometimes it need to wait for loading page

    return table

# --- main ---

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/Reports/Report_Menu_Web.aspx')

start_date = '01/05/2020'
end_date   = '27/05/2020'

for number, product in enumerate( ('Rice', 'Wheat', 'Tomato', 'Sugar') ):
    table = get_data(start_date, end_date, product)

    # for first product create file, for other products append to existing file
    if number == 0:
        mode = 'w'
    else:
        mode = 'a'

    # standard engine `xlsxwriter` can't append so I had to use `openpyxl`
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode=mode) as writer:
        table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=product, index=False)
```

Comment: I find out `append` doesn't work if `pandas` uses module `xlsxwriter` and I had to use install `openpyxl` and use `ExcelWriter(..., engine='openpyxl')`. BTW: I put your code in shorter version beacause you repeated some lines.

Comment: I changed full code - now I use `for`-loop to get different product.

Comment: That is wonderful! The code is concise now. Thank you so much for your inputs.